# Display number of actions by each user, grouped by the action ID

Tags: mysql, sql, django-admin

I did the following query for solving this question: **Count how many action each user performed** (Django admin).

```
SELECT Count(l.id),
       u.username, 
       u.first_name, 
       u.last_name, 
       u.is_staff 
FROM   django_admin_log l, auth_user u
WHERE  u.id = l.user_id
GROUP  BY u.id 
ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```

Now I want to Display how many actions where performed by each user, grouped by the action ID. The idea is the same of the query above, but knowing they action type.

**django_admin_log** table structure:

```
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| action_time     | datetime             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| content_type_id | int(11)              | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| object_id       | longtext             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| object_repr     | varchar(200)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| action_flag     | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| change_message  | longtext             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group by for the col not in aggregation function 
and in your case you should group by for user .. instance

```
  SELECT Count(l.id),
         u.username, 
         u.first_name, 
         u.last_name, 
         u.is_staff 
  FROM   django_admin_log l, auth_user u
  WHERE  u.id = l.user_id
  GROUP  BY  
          u.username, 
         u.first_name, 
         u.last_name, 
         u.is_staff 
  ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```